# How to read file and extract particular data in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to run shell script in which I need to read one file and extract some particular data from that file but i don't know how to extract data from a file.Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

`sltconfig.cfg` is the file from which i need to extract data.

```
iMedical_GCIP_Process_task_id=50018
iMedical_Early_Signal_Process_task_id=50019
```

If I run the process for GCIP then it should match GCIP in sltconfig.cfg file and extract id number.

Currently I have shell script like this:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]
then 
    python /medaff/Scripts/python/iMedical_Consumption_load_Procs.py "$1"
else
    echo "Pass the application name as argument"

fi
```

Here in $1 i am passing argument like -GCIP or Early_Signal. So first the process check the argument and match into sltconfig.cfg file and extract the Id number and print and then run the python script.

```
Run Command:

sh script_name.sh 'GCIP'

Expected Output:

ID Number= 50018
```

Please ask me if you need more info.

Comment: `awk -F= -v s="$1" '$1 ~ s{print "ID Number= " $2}' sltconfig.cfg`

Comment: @anubhava Hi sir.. Thank you for your response. Can you tell me how to save $2 value in a variable so that I can use this in other place of script.

Comment: `val2=$(awk -F= -v s="$1" '$1 ~ s{print $2}' sltconfig.cfg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one liner such as awk or simplify by breaking into different commands. 
First filter your

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then 
    line=`grep $1 sltconfig.cfg |head -1`
    param=`echo line | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`
    python /medaff/Scripts/python/iMedical_Consumption_load_Procs.py "${param}"
else
    echo "Pass the application name as argument"
fi
```